# Use of undeclared type Xcode with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

I am trying to refer to the app delegate in a UIButton Action that is in a Pods class in my workspace, however, I keep getting the error "Use of undeclared type". I believe this is due to the App Delegate being in the other workspace project. I would like to know how to fix it? Thank you.

**Button Code**

```
@IBAction func buttonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let paymentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("paymentViewController") as! AddCardViewController

    let paymentPageNav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: paymentViewController)

    let appDelegate:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

   appDelegate.drawerContainer!.centerViewController = paymentPageNav
   appDelegate.drawerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I get use of undeclared type for AddCardViewController, AppDelegate and MMDrawerSide.

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem with casting to custom controls from pods on my project, what solved it for me is to add `import` statement in the head of the file for my custom controller.

So if for example I am in `MainViewController.swift` and want to use a custom control/view/lib called `MyCustomController` imported with CocoaPods I add `import MyCustomController` after the `import UIKit`